# Como modificar caracteres en un array string java

Tags: java, array

Hola me podrían ayudar con un código?

De este array string en formato fecha tengo que obtener los primeros 4 caracteres que son dígitos, por ejemplo las posiciones deberían quedar así "0311", "2402", "3101", "2002"

```
String InStrArr[]= {"03/11/1103", "24/02/1991","31/01/1031","20/02/2002"};
```

Del resultado anterior debo hacer una rotación de los primeros dos caracteres con los siguientes dos caracteres y comparar si es posible generar el año basado en las rotaciones de día y mes, en caso de que si sea posible debe regresar el año en caso contrario una X.
Por ejemplo, en la primera posición si corresponde al año ya que al rotar 0311 da 1103.

Esto es lo que llevo (casi nada)

```
String InStrArr[]= {"03/11/1103", "24/02/1991","31/01/1031","20/02/2002"};
        
        
        
for(int i=0;i<InStrArr.length;i++) {
    String str=(String) InStrArr[i].subSequence(0, 5);
    String str1[]= {};
```

Espero me puedan ayudar....

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que sea buena idea usar un bucle `for`, ni un `subSequence` para rotar y extraer las cadenas, simplemente necesitas realizar un split en "/" y obtener los valores por separado, luego debes juntar mes+dia y comparar si es igual al año.

```
private String test(String string) {
    String[] split = string.split("/");
    
    string = split[1] + split[0];
    
    return (string.equals(split[2])) ? split[2] : "X";
}
```

Con el array que pasaste arriba

```
String[] fechas = {"03/11/1103", "24/02/1991","31/01/1031","20/02/2002"};
    
for (int i = 0; i < fechas.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(test(fechas[i]));
}
```

Devuelve esto

```
1103
X
X
X
```

Ya que rotando los otros días con meses ninguno coincide con el año

```
0224 - 1991
0131 - 1031
0220 - 2002
```